# Android inputstream returns null for bitmap for jpeg files

Tags: android, bitmap, httpconnection

I am always getting a bitmap return of null when I get an inputstream from an openhttpconnection that gets the url of a jpeg file.  For example, my url string is

```
 http://10.0.2.2:8000/mydirectory/myfile.jpg
```

where 8000 is the port for my local server running with an emulator.  I can use this same type of url to do gets from a webservice but not for getting an image file.  Is there something different I have to do to make a jpgeg file into a bitmap or is there something wrong with my url format?  Below is my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
  private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {

        Bitmap bmap = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;

        try {
            inStream = openHttpConnection(url);
            Log.d("inStream", String.valueOf(inStream));
            bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
            if(inStream != null)
                inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException el) {
            el.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmap;
    }

    private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {

        InputStream inStream = null;
        int checkConn = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        try {

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            checkConn = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (checkConn == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return inStream;
    }
```

Comment: try with a png image.

Comment: I can't use a png image.  I am working against an existing database that has all jpeg files.  This has to work with jpeg files.  If not, I am in trouble.

Comment: ok.. look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601820/bitmapfactory-decodestreaminputstream-always-return-null-when-some-bytes-are-w

Comment: I tried the method you referred to and it didn't work either.

Comment: Here is an example of what my inStream contains when looking at the logcat:  libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream@40f96c80.  Anyone know what that means?

Comment: type that URL in emulators browser. let me know if the image is displayed.

Comment: I have tried to read a png file and also from another server and get the same null bitmap.  I am getting these files in an asyntask method after having just gone through another asyntask to get the names of the files I need.  Is there a problem of having 2 different asyntasks going in the same program?  I am stumped!

Comment: TO Santhosh;  I don't know what you mean by typing in the URL in the emulator's browser.  What is the emulator's browser?