# BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returning null value

Tags: android, bitmap, cursor, buffer, byte

Here I am fetching value from **Cursor** :

```
    if (mProfileCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        byte[] blob = mProfileCursor.getBlob(
            mProfileCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI));
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream,1024);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    }
} finally {
    if (mProfileCursor != null) {
        mProfileCursor.close();
    }
}
```

I am trying to change byte[] into a bitmap but I am getting always **null**, according to answers in following post [Android: bitmapfactory.decodestream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650660/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-returns-null?rq=1) I tried **BufferedInputStream** but it is not working for me.
Also [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601820/bitmapfactory-decodestreaminputstream-always-return-null-when-some-bytes-are-w) here said that this is a known defect in android but answer is very old, please let me know if there is way for getting bitmap correct.

Comment: PHOTO_URI is a text, not blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public static final String PHOTO_URI

Added in API level 11
A URI that can be used to retrieve the contact's full-size photo. If PHOTO_FILE_ID is not null, this will be populated with a URI based off CONTENT_URI. Otherwise, this will be populated with the same value as PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI. A photo can be referred to either by a URI (this field) or by ID (see PHOTO_ID). If either PHOTO_FILE_ID or PHOTO_ID is not null, PHOTO_URI and PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI shall not be null (but not necessarily vice versa). Thus using PHOTO_URI is a more robust method of retrieving contact photos.

Type: TEXT

Constant Value: "photo_uri"

This is what the doc says, pskink is right, it returns a String. Also to add decodeStream returns null if it is not able to decode the image data and it would not generate any exception as well, so be carefull, check the values before using this.